# Python : Web scraping with Beautifulsoup - Why is the function get() not consistent?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I want to create a database of the companies in Switzerland, so I iterate a "for" loop on différents url links like this one : https://www.uid.admin.ch/Detail.aspx?uid_id=CHE106049755&lang=fr

I want to get the table of this page.

To iterate over different links, I just change the 9 last numbers of the link, because the "CHE---------" is a code for a specific company in Switzerland. However there are few codes that are not attributed, so for these codes we have an alert message in the website like this one :
https://www.uid.admin.ch/Detail.aspx?uid_id=CHE106049555&lang=en

I think that I did a correct script to create my database, however I get an issue that is not constant for one line : `test = soup.find(id="alertError").get("style")`

The error message : `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"`

When I say that it is not consistent, it is because sometimes it appears after 2 links, other times 3 or 10.

I tried with to switch the function "get()" by `test = soup.find(id="alertError")["style"]` but it gives the same mistake. What should I do that it iterates correctly ?

Thank you

My code :

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

#### ====================================================================
#### -------------------------- INPUT -----------------------------------
#### ====================================================================

limit_down = 106049700
limit_up = 106049800

url_begin = "https://www.uid.admin.ch/Detail.aspx?uid_id=CHE"
url_end = "&lang=fr"

#### ====================================================================
#### -------------------DECLARATION OF VARIABLES ------------------------
#### ====================================================================

list_number = np.arange(limit_down, limit_up)

dfs = []

#### ====================================================================
#### ---------------------- CREATE LIST OF DATA -------------------------
#### ====================================================================

def get_data(bs_soup) :

    data_column = bs_soup.find(class_="tab-content").find_all(class_="col-sm-2 control-label")
    data_row = bs_soup.find(class_="tab-content").find_all(style="padding:7px 12px")

    l_columns = []
    l_rows = np.array([])

    for label in data_column :
        
        l_columns.append(label.get_text().strip())

    for label in data_row :
        
        l_rows = np.append(l_rows, (label.get_text().strip()))

    l_columns.remove("Acheminable")
    l_rows = l_rows.reshape(1, -1)

    return l_columns, l_rows

#### ====================================================================
#### --------------------------- EXECUTION ------------------------------
#### ====================================================================

for i in list_number :
    
    #### GET DATA OF THE WEBSITE
    url = str(url_begin) + str(i) + str(url_end)
    print("\nThe link : "  + str(url))

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(response.content, "lxml")

    #### CONTROL IF IT HAS THE DATA THAT WE WANT

    test = soup.find(id="alertError").get("style")

    if test == "display: none" :

        list_columns, list_rows = get_data(soup)

        df = pd.DataFrame(list_rows, columns= list_columns)
        dfs = dfs.append(df)

    elif test == "display:;" :

        print("The link does not concern a company")

        pass


df_final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
df_final.to_excel("test_final")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says
`The error message : "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"` that means the element is not present on the page.

You can check whether element is present first.

```
test = soup.find(id="alertError")

if test:
    print("The link does not concern a company")        
else:
    list_columns, list_rows = get_data(soup)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_rows, columns=list_columns)
    dfs = dfs.append(df)
```